# JSON NSURLRequest with credentials

Tags: ios, json, parsing, swift

I have an api in my swift app that needs some extra authorization. There are some examples provided by the service but none in swift.

My Code:

```
    let request = NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "https://www.kimonolabs.com/api/au4sl00w?apikey=iFotcJDm95fB6Ua7XiZRDZA0jl3uYWev")!)
```

Example in Python

```
import urllib2
request = urllib2.Request("https://www.kimonolabs.com/api/au4sl00w? apikey=iFotcJDm95fB6Ua7XiZRDZA0jl3uYWev", headers={"authorization" : "Bearer    A5ve02gq40itf0eoYfT5ny6drZwcysxx"})
contents = urllib2.urlopen(request).read()
```

Example in Ruby

```
require 'rest_client'
response = RestClient.get('https://www.kimonolabs.com/api/au4sl00w?apikey=iFotcJDm95fB6Ua7XiZRDZA0jl3uYWev', {'authorization' => 'Bearer A5ve02gq40itf0eoYfT5ny6drZwcysxx'});
print(response);
```

Example in R

```
library('RCurl')
library('rjson')
json <- getURL('https://www.kimonolabs.com/api/au4sl00w?apikey=iFotcJDm95fB6Ua7XiZRDZA0jl3uYWuc',
  httpheader = c(authorization='Bearer A5ve02gq40itf0eoYfT5ny6drZwcysxx'))
obj <- fromJSON(json)
print(obj)
```

So, how can I do this in Swift?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Modified answer from: ["How to make an HTTP request + basic auth in Swift"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24379601/how-to-make-an-http-request-basic-auth-in-swift).

I believe it would look something like this (and assuming your `API_ID` is `au4sl00w`) :

```
let token = "yourToken"

// create the request
let url = NSURL(string: "https://www.kimonolabs.com/api/au4sl00w?apikey=iFotcJDm95fB6Ua7XiZRDZA0jl3uYWev")
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
request.HTTPMethod = "GET"
request.setValue("Bearer \(token)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
```

And be sure to create a new access token, now that this one is public :)

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. I don't want a username and password. I need this token Bearer A5ve02gq40itf0eoYfT5ny6drZwcysxx as authorisation. Can you still help?

Comment: Oh! Im sorry, I misread. But I think it's about the same steps, just update: `request.setValue("Bearer \(yourToken)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization"` (I'll be sure to update my answer if this was in fact what you were looking for)

Comment: Thanks for that. With my request (First code in question) what do I need to change.

Comment: Hello, Don't worry. I figured it out.         let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "https://www.kimonolabs.com/api/au4sl00w?apikey=iFotcJDm95fB6Ua7XiZRDZA0jl3uYW")!)

Comment: Thanks for updating your question also. Very helpful!