# Making HTTP Request with header in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlsession, imgur

I am trying to make an HTTP request to the Imgur API. I am trying to retrieve all images associated with the tag "cats." The url, according to the Imgur API is: https://api.imgur.com/3/gallery/t/cats

the Imgur API states the following about the authorization needed to make get requests:

> For public read-only and anonymous resources, such as getting image 
>   info, looking up user comments, etc. all you need to do is send an 
>   authorization header with your `client_id` in your requests. This also 
>   works if you'd like to upload images anonymously (without the image
>   being tied to an account), or if you'd like to create an anonymous
>   album. This lets us know which application is accessing the API.
>
> ```
> Authorization: Client-ID YOUR_CLIENT_ID
> ```

I've looked at the following questions and tried things suggested there, but none of them have helped.

[JSON NSURLRequest with credentials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27956943/json-nsurlrequest-with-credentials?lq=1)

[Swift GET request with parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27723912/swift-get-request-with-parameters)

[How to make a Http get and set httpHeader in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27814050/how-to-make-a-http-get-and-set-httpheader-in-swift)

My current code is this:

```
let string = "https://api.imgur.com/3/gallery/t/cats"
let url = NSURL(string: string)
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!)
request.setValue("clientIDhere", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
//request.addValue("clientIDhere", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
request.HTTPMethod = "GET"
let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

let tache = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) { (data, response, error) -> Void in
    if let antwort = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse {
        let code = antwort.statusCode
        print(code)
    }
}
tache.resume()
```

But I continually get a status code of 403, meaning authorization is required. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Something's amiss, perhaps in your problem description, because the Authorization Required code is 401: `{"data":{"error":"Authentication required","request":"\/3\/gallery\/t\/cats","method":"GET"},"success":false,"status":401}` when doing exactly the above unauth'd HTTP GET from Chrome browser. 403 is 'Forbidden' meaning no amount of authorization will allow you to get that page, it's just a locked off area.

Comment: when copy/pasting that url into the browser, I get the same response, status code of 401. But when running it in Xcode, the status code is 403. If I remove the request.setValue method in Xcode, the status code changes to 401.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I think you need to prepend **Client-ID** string to your actual client ID  as for the header value:

```
request.setValue("Client-ID <your_client_id>", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
```

Comment: Can you help me. I am doing the same thing for google books api but i am getting Invalid Credentials. Please let me know if you can help me.

Answer (score 5):

***Updated for swift 4 :***

```
func fetchPhotoRequest(YOUR_CLIENT_ID: String)  {
    let string = "https://photoslibrary.googleapis.com/v1/albums"
    let url = NSURL(string: string)
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url! as URL)
    request.setValue(YOUR_CLIENT_ID, forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization") //**
    request.httpMethod = "GET"
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    let session = URLSession.shared

    let mData = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) { (data, response, error) -> Void in
        if let res = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
            print("res: \(String(describing: res))")
            print("Response: \(String(describing: response))")
        }else{
            print("Error: \(String(describing: error))")
        }
    }
    mData.resume()
}
```