# Make a http request with basic authentication

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I want to make an http request with basic auth. I tried to follow this topic : [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24379601/how-to-make-an-http-request-basic-auth-in-swift?s=4%7C0.6752). But Xcode tell me

> Bad Request after httpResponse

And I don't know why since this morning. Maybe anyone got a idea more interesting than I can find on the web ? :)

Here is my code :

```
func topRefresh(sender:AnyObject){

    var list=Array<Notification>()

    //credential
    let credentialLogin = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("login") as! String
    let credentialPassword = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("password") as! String

    // set up the base64-encoded credentials
    let loginString = NSString(format: "%@:%@", credentialLogin, credentialPassword)
    let loginData: NSData = loginString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
    let base64LoginString = loginData.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions.Encoding64CharacterLineLength)

    // create the request
    let url = NSURL(string: jsonLink)!
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
    request.cachePolicy = NSURLRequestCachePolicy.ReloadIgnoringCacheData
    request.setValue("Basic \(base64LoginString)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
    request.HTTPMethod="GET"
    let paramString="login="+credentialLogin
    request.HTTPBody = paramString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)

    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
        (data, response, error) -> Void in

        let httpResponse = response as! NSHTTPURLResponse

        if (httpResponse.statusCode == 200) {
            do{
                if  (data != nil){
                    self.notificationsDisplayed.removeAll()
                    let jsonDict = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!,options: .AllowFragments)
                    list=self.parseJson(jsonDict)

                    if (self.notifications.count==0){
                        self.notifications=self.copyArray(list)
                        list.removeAll()
                    }else{
                        //compare new data with past data
                        while(list.count>0){
                            print(list.count)

                            let tmp=list.last
                            for notification in self.notifications {
                                if(tmp!.id==notification.id){
                                    list.removeLast()
                                    break
                                }else{
                                    self.notifications.insert(tmp!, atIndex: 0)
                                    list.removeLast()
                                    break
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    self.orderByDate(&self.notifications)
                    self.notificationsDisplayed=self.copyArray(self.notifications)
                    self.applyFilter()
                    print("Data parsed")
                }else{
                    print("Data is empty")
                }

            }catch {
                print("Error with Json: \(error)")
            }
        }else{
            print("HTTP Error")
        }
        self.refreshControl?.endRefreshing()
        print("Finished")
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use the following in my code to create a default session that include the authentication:

```
static func defaultURLSession(username : String, password:String) -> NSURLSession {
    let config = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
    let userPasswordString = "\(username):\(password)"
    let userPasswordData = userPasswordString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    let base64EncodedCredential = userPasswordData!.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions.EncodingEndLineWithCarriageReturn)
    let authString = "Basic \(base64EncodedCredential)"
    config.HTTPAdditionalHeaders = ["Authorization" : authString]

    return NSURLSession(configuration: config)
}
```

Comment: I have to use a session instead of the request to authenticate the user ?