# Basic auth in swift 5 in iOS

Tags: ios, api, basic-authentication, swift5, urlsession

I have referred to many posts with regard to the question I have. Below are the link I have referred,

- [How to make an HTTP request + basic auth in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24379601/how-to-make-an-http-request-basic-auth-in-swift)
- https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/68809
- [Make a http request with basic authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37346020/make-a-http-request-with-basic-authentication)
- https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/32

The basic authentication in swift 5/XCode 12 version is failing. I get the below error in xcode,

```
2021-07-08 15:28:32.693835+0200 App[43664:810014] Connection 1: encountered error(3:-9816)
2021-07-08 15:33:33.042464+0200 App[43664:821863] Connection 2: received failure notification
2021-07-08 15:33:33.042685+0200 App[43664:821863] Connection 2: failed to connect 3:-9816, reason -1
```

Below is the code I am using (I am using urlsession),

```
var mhUrlRequest = URLRequest(url: mhURL)
let userPasswordData = "username:password".data(using: .utf8)
let base64EncodedCredential = userPasswordData!.base64EncodedString(options: Data.Base64EncodingOptions.init(rawValue: 0))
let authString = "Basic \(base64EncodedCredential)"
mhUrlRequest.setValue(authString, forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
```

I even tried the below code

```
let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
config.httpAdditionalHeaders = ["Authorization" : authString]
```

But none of these seems to work for me.

Comment: -9816 points to an ssl error. Are you using https? Is your certificate valid and trusted? Are you using strong ciphers?

Comment: Yes.. It https. I have a valid certificate and it is trusted. The services are working fine in Postman. In Postman the basic auth is working but not in iOS

Comment: iOS ATS can be more strict on TLS than postman.  The error isn't to do with basic authentication. You are getting a connection failure. Is your device time correct?

Comment: could you find the answer?

Answer (score 0):

The conversion of the credentials to base64 is not the better way. Try these code

```
let url = "your_url"
let usu_pass = "username:password"
var authData = (usu_pass.data(using: .utf8)?.base64EncodedString())!

let url = URL(string:url)
let header = [
    "content-type" : "text/xml",
     "Authorization" : "Basic " + authData
]
        
var request = URLRequest(url: url!)
request.allHTTPHeaderFields = header
request.httpMethod = "POST"
...
```