# Can't load http authorisation website url in webview on IOS9 with swift 2

Tags: ios, swift, webview, uiwebview

I'm now to IOS development and i encounter a problem that i can't load a http authorisation site in webview, it just show blank page and nothing comes out, here is my code to load the website:

```
@IBAction func testhttp(sender: AnyObject) {

    let url = NSURL(string: "http://www.obee.com.au/demo/admin/index.php");
    let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!);
    //see2 is the webview....
    see2.loadRequest(request);
}
```

Can anyone help me fix this problem ?

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like it needs an authentication to load the page. You might fix it with providing credential info in the header of NSURLRequest.

[How to make an HTTP request + basic auth in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24379601/how-to-make-an-http-request-basic-auth-in-swift)

Answer (score 1):

Add Following Line Code in `info.plist`:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

Screen shot:

[image: NSAlowArbitaryLoads]

Comment: Hi sakir, i have add those code to info.plist, but it still show blank, idk why

Answer (score 0):

Go to your **plist**, Right click on **Information property list** click **add new row** then add new row as **app transport security system** and inside this row **add allow arbitrary load** as **yes**

[image]