# How to use WS-Security [WSS] SOAP in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, soap, ws-security, wss

**Web service**

How to connect a web service in Swift that uses WS-Security and Send HttpBody data. ?

I try this [How to make an HTTP request + basic auth in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24379601/how-to-make-an-http-request-basic-auth-in-swift)

I use this librery https://github.com/priore/SOAPEngine

```
    let soap = SOAPEngine()
    soap.licenseKey = "12324351242345xxss3ews"
    soap.actionNamespaceSlash = true

    soap.authorizationMethod = SOAPAuthorization.AUTH_WSSECURITY_TEXT
    soap.username = "user"
    soap.password = "test.password"



    soap.envelope = "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:com1='http://www.rbm.com.co/esb/comercio/' xmlns:esb='http://www.rbm.com.co/esb/' xmlns:soapenv='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' xmlns:com='http://www.rbm.com.co/esb/comercio/compra/'><soapenv:Header /><soapenv:Body> <com:compraProcesarSolicitud><com:cabeceraSolicitud><com:infoPuntoInteraccion><com1:tipoTerminal>WEB</com1:tipoTerminal><com1:idTerminal>ESB10434</com1:idTerminal><com1:idAdquiriente>0010203040</com1:idAdquiriente> <com1:idTransaccionTerminal>789654</com1:idTransaccionTerminal><com1:modoCapturaPAN>Manual</com1:modoCapturaPAN><com1:capacidadPIN>Virtual</com1:capacidadPIN></com:infoPuntoInteraccion></com:cabeceraSolicitud><com:idPersona><esb:tipoDocumento>CC</esb:tipoDocumento><esb:numDocumento>123456789</esb:numDocumento></com:idPersona><com:infoMedioPago><com:idTarjetaCredito><esb:franquicia>MasterCard</esb:franquicia><esb:numTarjeta>5303710409428783</esb:numTarjeta><esb:fechaExpiracion>2019-03-30</esb:fechaExpiracion><esb:codVerificacion>742</esb:codVerificacion></com:idTarjetaCredito></com:infoMedioPago><com:infoCompra><com:montoTotal>22222.00</com:montoTotal><com:infoImpuestos><esb:tipoImpuesto>Consumo</esb:tipoImpuesto><esb:monto>3065.00</esb:monto><esb:baseImpuesto>19157.00</esb:baseImpuesto></com:infoImpuestos> <com:montoDetallado><esb:tipoMontoDetallado>BaseDevolucionIVA</esb:tipoMontoDetallado><esb:monto>19157.00</esb:monto></com:montoDetallado><com:referencia>Frisby App iOS</com:referencia><com:cantidadCuotas>1</com:cantidadCuotas></com:infoCompra></com:compraProcesarSolicitud></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>"


    soap.requestURL("https://www.123345.com/test/",
                    soapAction: "action",
                    completeWithDictionary: { (statusCode: Int?, dict: [AnyHashable: Any]?) -> Void in


                        print("\(String(describing: dict))")                           



    }) { (error: Error?) -> Void in

        print(error!)
    }
```

The server return this "illegal character '<' at line 2"

Comment: Did you actually do any research on the topic? What did you try so far? What is not working?

Comment: Yes i try this sample https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24379601/how-to-make-an-http-request-basic-auth-in-swift

Comment: Then include the actual code in your question and explain how is it not working...

Comment: ok one moment pls

Comment: please do not post any confidential info like licenseKey. Remove it for your security

Comment: thx the this licenseKey is trial

Comment: have you added ATS in plist as mention in this link https://github.com/priore/SOAPEngine.

Comment: @AndresMarin even though I have already asked twice, you still didn't include a description of what is wrong with the code. For a question asking for debugging help to be considered on topic here on SO, it needs to contain the code causing the issue, the expected behaviour and the actual behaviour. Your question is still off-topic, since it is lacking the latter.

Comment: yes, the server return this "illegal character '<' at line 2"

Comment: @Dávid Pásztor sorry my english is not very good, the server return "illegal character '<' at line 2" but in the SoapUI the server return correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution. add in the httpBody.

```
<soapenv:Header>
    <wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1"
        xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
        <wsse:UsernameToken>
            <wsse:Username>USER</wsse:Username>
            <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">Password</wsse:Password>
        </wsse:UsernameToken>
    </wsse:Security>
</soapenv:Header>
```

Answer (score 0):

soap.envelope must only contain the additional namespace, like below:

```
soap.envelope = "xmlns:com1='http://www.rbm.com.co/esb/comercio/' xmlns:esb='http://www.rbm.com.co/esb/'"
```

and set parameters like below:

```
soap.setValue("WEB", forKey: "com1:tipoTerminal")
```

or more complex parameters :

```
let dict = ["esb:tipoDocumento":"CC", "esb:numDocumento": "1234567890"]
soap.setValue(dict, forKey: "com:idPersona")
```