# Swift equivalent of Python requests.session()?

Tags: swift, request

In python, we can authenticate a request like this

```
session = requests.session()
session.auth = ("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")
r = session.get('https://example.com/api/v1/method').json()
```

How can we do this in swift? Is there a built-in class for this?

Answer (score 1):

This is a common authorization feature as known as Basic access authentication

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication

It works this way.
You append base64-encoded string in the request header for value "Authorization". This string has got this format :

So, for swift 4 you have to use this way:

```
let username = "user"
let password = "pass"
let loginString = String(format: "%@:%@", username, password)
let loginData = loginString.data(using: .utf8)!
let base64LoginString = loginData.base64EncodedString()

var request = URLRequest(url: url)
request.setValue("Basic \(base64LoginString)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
```

detailed example is here

https://stackoverflow.com/a/24380884/1979882